# Recursively move files with different names and different extensions

Tags: find, rename

How can I recursively find all audio and video files in a directory and move them elsewhere in a single operation?

Comment: Do you have a set of file extensions that you're trying to process? If they're enumerable please do so (in your question)

Comment: roaima - Multimedia files, like avi,m4v,mov,mp4,mpeg,mpg,wmv,flv,webm,ogv,mkv,mp3, etc. About 2 dozen possible extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `find` command allows you to limit what files are matched.  You can then call your script with the `exec` option
e.g.

```
find . \( -name '*.mp3' -o -name '*.avi' \) -exec /path/to/your/script.sh
```

Now your script will be called for each mp3/avi file in the tree.

A simple test to show this would be to have script.sh read something like

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Script called with "$1" as the filename
```

Now you can build your script to call `ffmpeg` or whatever you like.

Comment: Stephen Harris - I would have bet my bottom dollar that I tried this one, but I changed the mp3 to mp4 as I knew there were some in there somewhere and it worked. A little inelegant perhaps, but most of the extensions I was planning on including were only possibilities, and along with a few other changes I have planned I can limit the likely ones to about six. Thanks for the help. I'll mark it solved.

Comment: Stephen Harris - I should also point out that I used mv {} ./ \; instead of path/to/script...Thanks again for taking the time to help me.